# How to have a page display certain categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am sorry if my title is a little long winded but I am new to Wordpress and doing my best to learn it.

I am currently using Wordpress 3.1.3 and just working on the Twenty Ten theme.

Right now my goal is to have the homepage to display "News" "Update" categories then I'll have another page to display "reviews & "articles"

How can I achieve this?

Thank you,
Art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post on designershq should help you out:

http://designershq.net/wordpress-help/show-posts-by-category/

Comment: Im sorry I am very new at this, it is the right code really does help but where do I put this code?

Comment: create a copy of index.php and add the line `<?php query_posts(‘cat=1&showposts=3′); ?>` above `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` where `cat=1` is the ids for the categories you want to show.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Contact me if you need any more help or advice.

Comment: One thing actually really quick sorry, this has worked so well for me in what I wanted to achieve, now I have my homepage showing news & updates etc, how can I actually have the remaining categories to display on another page?

Comment: copy index.php as a new file. then you'll need to make this a template, like so:
`<?php
/*
Template Name: The Template Name
*/
?>`

Answer (score 0):

WP_LIST_CATEGORY()

you can list all the  category by this function  also  you can visit  wordpress codex for the function detail